# Formatting a date column in a CSV file in 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' to 'YYYYMMDD HH24MISS' format in ksh

Tags: postgresql, csv, unix, awk, ksh

I wrote a script which takes values from a CSV file and inserts in into a postgres table, but was facing a problem.
The date columns in the CSV file are in 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' format, and the same column in the table are defined as Timestamp, and when inserting using the \copy command, I am getting the below error,

`ERROR: 22008: date/time field value out of range: "20000125200942"`

So I tried few things and figured out if I have the entries in 'YYYYMMDD HH24MISS' format, the insert works fine.

Now the problem is I don't know how to format the entries of the CSV file in ksh.

I tried using the gsub command with awk, but it didn't seem to work.

`awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {gsub(/^([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})$/, "\\1\\2\\3 \\4\\5\\6", $1)} 1' input_file.csv > output_file.csv`

All your help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you add a sample of the input file and expected output for such sample?

Comment: Sure, basically the input file (comma separated CSV file) has a date column, for eg. '20000125200942,xxxxx,xxxx' and want it formatted as             '20000125 200942,xxxxx,xxxx'

Comment: please update the question with the sample inputs, the (wrong) output generated by your script, and the (correct) expected output, making sure both sets of output correspond to the sample set of inputs

Comment: if you want the new format to be `YYYYMMDD HHMMSS` ... why are you inserting dashes and colons in your code (`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`)? which format do you *need* to suply to postgres?

Comment: `gsub()` doesn't support backreferences like `\\1` (nor does `sub()`). You may be thinking of `gensub()` which is supported by gawk and a couple of these these days but is not part of POSIX.

Comment: What does `HH24MISS` mean for the time format? Do you just mean `HHMMSS` (as your code and the timestamp in your error message, `20000125200942`, seem to indicate) or something else? Please [edit] your question to clarify that and provide concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Comment: Did you try the method I suggested in comment to your previous iteration of this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75745394/shell-script-to-insert-data-into-postgres-table-using-a-csv-file?

Comment: @markp-fuso sorry for the error, i pasted the wrong code, I was also trying to convert the date into this format 

Comment: @AdrianKlaver yes, but I wanted to do this without creating a temp table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumptions:

- all inputs (1st field) consist of exactly 14 digits in `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` format

Sample input:

```
$ cat input_file.csv
20000125200942,xxxxx,xxxx
```

One `awk` idea where we redefine the 1st field (`$1`) with a pair of substrings separated by a space:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {$1=substr($1,1,8) " " substr($1,9)} 1' input_file.csv > output_file.csv
```

This generates:

```
$ cat output_file.csv
20000125 200942,xxxxx,xxxx
```

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `awk`:

```
echo 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""} {$9=" " $9}1'
```

With GNU `sed`:

```
echo 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' | sed -E 's/^.{8}/& /'
```

Output:

```
YYYYMMDD HH24MISS
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F, '{sub(/^[0-9]{8}/,"& "); print "date:", $1}' <<<'20000125200942,xxxxx,xxxx'
date: 20000125 200942

$ awk 'sub(/^[0-9]{8}/,"& ")' input_file.csv > output_file.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following GNU `awk` code.

```
awk 'match($0,/^([0-9]{8})([^,].*)$/,arr){print arr[1],arr[2]}' Input_file
```